# Pop only one item from lru_cache in Python

Tags: python, caching, functools

I'm using the `lru_cache` decorator from `functools`, and I need to invalidate *only one* item in it, and leave the rest unchanged. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) states that the `__wrapped__` attribute is there for rewrapping the function with a different cache. I checked the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/functools.py#L448) too, but I can't figure out how to use that. It says that

> Users should only access the lru_cache through its public API:
> cache_info, cache_clear, and f.__wrapped__
> The internals of the lru_cache are encapsulated for thread safety and
> to allow the implementation to change

Is is possible to remove one item from `lru_cache` (safely), or should I write my own cache functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lru_cache` in Python 3.9 does not even expose in Python anything but the public API - which include a `cache_clear` call that will invalidate the whole cache, not just a key.

Thus, instead of finding a workaround for that, you are clearly better-off writing your own cache where you can have full control.

The `__wrapped__`  attribute itself is just the original function, with no lru_cache functionality at all. Actually, you can make use of it to *bypass* the cache for one call completely - and the function will just run with the repeated parameters as an ordinay Python function - but its response won't be cached at all.

That is, for

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def test(a):
   print("side effect")

test(23)
test.__wrapped__(23)
```

the function body is run for both calls.